# JSF composite component id for use in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf, composite-component

i want to write a composite component in jsf and add some functionality by jquery.

Little example:
My composite component definition looks like this:

```
[...]
<t:inputText
    id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
    value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
    required="false"/>

<h:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.required}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document.getElementById("#{cc.attrs.id}")).addClass("mandatory")
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>
[...]
```

and will result in something like this:

```
<input name="content_form:name:name" id="content_form:name:name" type="text" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document.getElementById("name")).addClass("mandatory")
</script>
```

As you can see jquery is getting the wrong id. This happens becaus the evaluation of #{cc.attrs.id} seems ot happen at different points.

How is it possible to get predictable ids or is there a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case i found a "working solution":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document.getElementById("#{cc.clientId}:#{cc.attrs.id}")).addClass("mandatory")
</script>
```

will be rendered with the "real id" of my input element.

Explanation:

cc.clientId returns the id of the composite component we are in, result: ("content_form:name")

cc.attrs.id will return the value of the id attribute, result: ("name")

This can be concatenate to "content_form:name:name" and be used as Id for jquery.

I know this is not "getting the id" from the input-tag it, is predicting the result.

It works, but if somebody knows a better way to do
it, i'm glat to hear about.